# Sorting and Pagination in Angular (latest version)

Tags: angular

I was trying to create a datatable in angular project and my basis is this [website](https://blog.logrocket.com/angular-datatables-feature-rich-tables/). I executed the source code and there's no error but in my case the button to show entries, sorting, and pagination is not appearing. What am i missing? Need help guys. PS. I already installed the plugins and import the module.

## HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped" datatable [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Tin</th>
            <th scope="col">Corporate Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Contact Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Business Address</th>
            <th scope="col">Date of Registration</th>
            <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center; width: 15%">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let user of allUsers">
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.address.zipcode }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.company.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.address.street }}, {{ user.address.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">
                <i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>
              </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
              </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="bi bi-eye"></i>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

## TYPESCRIPT

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/service/data.service';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-overall',
  templateUrl: './overall.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./overall.component.scss']
})
export class OverallComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective, { static: false })
  private dtElement!: DataTableDirective;
  
  overall: any
  allUsers: any;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  
  constructor(private service: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.service.users().subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.allUsers = res;
        });
        this.dtOptions = {
        pagingType: 'full_numbers', // Enable pagination
        order: [[0, 'asc']], // Enable sorting on the first column (index 0)
      };
  }
  rerender(): void {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
       dtInstance.destroy();
       this.dtTrigger.next(undefined);     
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

[MY OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlQzn.png)

[OUTPUT I WANT TO TRY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAx8N.png)

Comment: Has you install property the angular-tables (see the [instalation](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started): add query, add in module and change the angular.json? See that you not call to this.renderer in any place (I imagine you need call it under subscribe function, but I'm not prety sure). NOTE: Personally I think that use jQuery and Angular (when you use angular-datatables you need add jQuery) it's a **bad** idea. I suggest look for others data-tables

Comment: Yes, I already installed all the property but the output is still the same

Comment: See that you use `@ViewChild(DataTableDirective, { static: false })`. If you use static:false, remember that you can **not** put your table under a *ngIf. I have no more idea than what it's happened :(. BTW try remove the `order: [[0, 'asc']],` to prove.